# How do I fix error with using SAML in Hue application

Tags: saml, cloudera, hue

I got a problem for using saml function in hue application.

I did every thing what I need to do in following this : https://docs.gethue.com/latest/administrator/configuration/server/#saml

env

os : ubuntu
hue : 4.5.0

**step 1.** install below

git gcc python-dev swig openssl xmlsec1 libxmlsec1-openssl

**step 2.** copy metadata from Idp to local

**step 3.** make a private key and certification with openssl

**step 4.** set configuration ini file

```
[[auth]] 
backend=libsaml.backend.SAML2Backend 
[libsaml]
xmlsec_binary=/usr/bin/xmlsec1
metadata_file=/opt/cloudera/security/saml/idp-openam-metadata.xml
key_file=/opt/cloudera/security/saml/host.key
cert_file=/opt/cloudera/security/saml/host.pem username_source=nameid
entity_id=https://myhuedomainname.com/saml2/metadata
```

**step 5.** get hue metadata and register it at Idp

I got my hue metadata at : https://myhuedomainname.com/saml2/metadata
and I registered it at Idp that our company use.

I think I did everything right.

but when I access to https://myhuedomainname.com, 
my browser is redirected to :https://myhuedomainname.com/saml2/login/?next=/
then I got error that I cannot solved

it is empty screen that is redirected to same url again and again.

[image]

in browser console, I got this error

> i18n.js:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: HUE_I18n is not defined
>       at I18n (i18n.js:17)
>       at Module../desktop/core/src/desktop/js/jquery/plugins/jquery.filechooser.js
>   (hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:47211)
>       at **webpack_require** (hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:104)
>       at Module../desktop/core/src/desktop/js/jquery/jquery.common.js (hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:46742)
>       at **webpack_require** (hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:104)
>       at Module../desktop/core/src/desktop/js/hue.js (hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:46485)
>       at **webpack_require** (hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:104)
>       at Object.0 (hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:104841)
>       at **webpack_require** (hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:104)
>       at checkDeferredModules (hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:65)
>
> I18n @ i18n.js:17
>   ./desktop/core/src/desktop/js/jquery/plugins/jquery.filechooser.js @
>   hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:47211
>   **webpack_require** @ hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:104 ./desktop/core/src/desktop/js/jquery/jquery.common.js @
>   hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:46742
>   **webpack_require** @ hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:104 ./desktop/core/src/desktop/js/hue.js @
>   hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:46485
>   **webpack_require** @ hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:104 0 @ hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:104841
>   **webpack_require** @ hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:104 checkDeferredModules @ hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:65
>   (anonymous) @ hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:241
>   (anonymous) @ hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js:sourcemap:244
>
> bootstrap-tooltip.js:326 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn'
>   of undefined
>       at bootstrap-tooltip.js:326
>       at bootstrap-tooltip.js:361 (anonymous) @ bootstrap-tooltip.js:326 (anonymous) @ bootstrap-tooltip.js:361
>
> bootstrap-typeahead-touchscreen.js:317 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'fn' of undefined
>       at bootstrap-typeahead-touchscreen.js:317
>       at bootstrap-typeahead-touchscreen.js:358 (anonymous) @ bootstrap-typeahead-touchscreen.js:317 (anonymous) @
>   bootstrap-typeahead-touchscreen.js:358
>
> bootstrap-better-typeahead.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'extend' of undefined
>       at bootstrap-better-typeahead.min.js:12
>       at bootstrap-better-typeahead.min.js:12 (anonymous) @ bootstrap-better-typeahead.min.js:12 (anonymous) @
>   bootstrap-better-typeahead.min.js:12
>
> popover-extra-placements.js:113 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not
>   defined
>       at popover-extra-placements.js:113 (anonymous) @ popover-extra-placements.js:113
>
> ?next=/:123 Uncaught ReferenceError: Dropzone is not defined
>       at ?next=/:123 (anonymous) @ ?next=/:123

below is the logs of hue

> [23/Sep/2019 21:50:34 +0000] middleware   INFO     Redirecting to
>   login page: / [23/Sep/2019 21:50:34 +0000] access       INFO
>   210.94.41.89, 34.96.109.171 -anon- - "GET / HTTP/1.1" (mem: 158mb)-- login redirection [23/Sep/2019 21:50:34 +0000] access       INFO
>   210.94.41.89, 34.96.109.171 -anon- - "GET / HTTP/1.1" returned in 1ms (mem: 158mb) [23/Sep/2019 21:50:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
>   [23/Sep/2019 21:50:34] "GET
>   /static/desktop/js/bundles/hue/hue-bundle-facb48d1fb2c72ee1343.js.map
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 7139914 [23/Sep/2019 21:50:35 +0000] access       DEBUG 
>   210.94.41.89, 34.96.109.171 -anon- - "GET /saml2/login/ HTTP/1.1" (mem: 158mb) [23/Sep/2019 21:50:35 +0000] mdstore      DEBUG
>   service => {'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST':
>   [{'binding': 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
>   '**class**':
>   'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata&SingleSignOnService',
>   'location': 'https://sts.secsso.net/adfs/ls/'}],
>   'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect': [{'binding':
>   'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect', '**class**':
>   'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata&SingleSignOnService',
>   'location': 'https://sts.secsso.net/adfs/ls/'}]} [23/Sep/2019 21:50:35
>   +0000] mdstore      DEBUG    service => {'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST': [{'binding':
>   'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST', '**class**':
>   'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata&SingleSignOnService',
>   'location': 'https://sts.secsso.net/adfs/ls/'}],
>   'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect': [{'binding':
>   'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect', '**class**':
>   'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata&SingleSignOnService',
>   'location': 'https://sts.secsso.net/adfs/ls/'}]} [23/Sep/2019 21:50:35
>   +0000] mdstore      DEBUG    service(http://sts.secsso.net/adfs/services/trust, idpsso_descriptor,
>   single_sign_on_service, None) [23/Sep/2019 21:50:35 +0000] mdstore
>   DEBUG    service => {'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST':
>   [{'binding': 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
>   '**class**':
>   'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata&SingleSignOnService',
>   'location': 'https://sts.secsso.net/adfs/ls/'}],
>   'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect': [{'binding':
>   'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect', '**class**':
>   'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata&SingleSignOnService',
>   'location': 'https://sts.secsso.net/adfs/ls/'}]} [23/Sep/2019 21:50:35
>   +0000] mdstore      DEBUG    service(http://sts.secsso.net/adfs/services/trust, idpsso_descriptor,
>   single_sign_on_service,
>   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect) [23/Sep/2019
>   21:50:35 +0000] mdstore      DEBUG    service => [{'binding':
>   'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect', '**class**':
>   'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata&SingleSignOnService',
>   'location': 'https://sts.secsso.net/adfs/ls/'}] [23/Sep/2019 21:50:35
>   +0000] client       INFO     destination to provider: https://sts.secsso.net/adfs/ls/ [23/Sep/2019 21:50:35 +0000] entity
>   INFO     REQUEST: 
>   https://sbc-hue.mgmt.dev.com/saml2/metadata/ [23/Sep/2019 21:50:35 +0000] client       INFO
>   AuthNReq:  https://sbc-hue.mgmt.dev.com/saml2/metadata/ [23/Sep/2019 21:50:35 +0000] entity       INFO
>   HTTP REDIRECT [23/Sep/2019 21:50:35 +0000] views        WARNING  User 
>   is using Hue 3 UI [23/Sep/2019 21:50:35 +0000] decorators   INFO
>   AXES: Calling decorated function: dt_login [23/Sep/2019 21:50:35
>   +0000] decorators   INFO     args: (True,) [23/Sep/2019 21:50:35 +0000] access       INFO     210.94.41.89, 34.96.109.171 -anon- - "GET /saml2/login/ HTTP/1.1" returned in 250ms (mem: 158mb)

I tried it with hue 4.0.0 version but it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it with setting 'redirect_whitelist'.
I just though it is not mandatory. but it is